# Error in my Matlab code?

Tags: matlab

I would like to make some calculation on my Raman spectra, I have a problem to read my input file. My file `.txt` contain 2 columns: `X = Wavelength` (cm-1) and `Y = Raman intensity`. The name of the file contains the coordinates of the position or the Raman spectrum was collected, for example `(0.00,-05.00)` or `(-2.00,-0.50)`.

```
function Read_Raman_Files
% Reads Raman spectra from txt files.
% Each file contains the data for a single Raman spectrum:
%  X = Wavelength (cm-1)
%  Y = Raman intensity
% The name of the input file contains the coordinates at which the spectrum is taken.
% Results are stored in 'data.mat'.

files = dir('-5.0,0.00.txt');
Ncurves = length(files);
if Ncurves==0, display('No txt files found!'); return; end
for i = 1:Ncurves,
    i
    fname = files(i).name;
    data = importdata(fname);
    if i==1, X = data(:,i); end
    Y(:,i) = data(:,2);
    dash = strfind(fname,'__');
    Xpos(i) = str2num(fname(strfind(fname,'Xµm_')+4:dash(2)-1));
    Ypos(i) = str2num(fname(strfind(fname,'Yµm_')+4:dash(3)-1));
end;
save('data.mat', 'Ncurves', 'X', 'Y', 'Xpos', 'Ypos');
return
```

Comment: your code contains serival syntex errors. Will you tell me what kind of calculations you want to perform on X and Y then i shall modify your code according to that?

Comment: The error is...what?

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, i'm using an open source matlab code for fitting my spectra and plot a map, i can't post a link to this code in this forum, but you can get it in Google (search Amir Zabet raman matlab, the first link)

Comment: @Ben  what you want to do? Want to just plot X and Y? What you want to do with Lat and lon? is this more than one text files in your folder?

Comment: I have a map 900 points (input file .txt), for each point a i have 4 informations (4 columns) Wavelength (cm-1), Y = Raman intensity and  Xpos, Ypos (the coordinates of each point). I have a script (4 files .m) to entre the file .txt and then make a fit of my spectra and plot a specific informations. The problem is that the input file doesn't work. If you have an email we could discuss in rpivate. Thank you for you help

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does your computer explode? Is a black hole generated? Does it play a song?

Comment: doesn't work" means thaht the sciprt doenn't read my input file ! Could us discuss by email ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to read the content of a file that has 2 columns of integers separated by comma:

```
formatSpec = '%d%d';
[x, y] = textread('yourFile.txt', formatSpec, 'delimiter',',');
```

Comment: Thank you for you replay, i would like to insert a txt file with data. 
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in Read_Raman_Files (line 17)
 Y(:,i) = data(:,2);

Comment: dir lists files and folders in the current folder. If you want to read the content of a txt file you can use textscan, textread or csvread. Check the updated response.

Comment: Thank you i will try to do that